# JAXB unmarshall not filling in fields with data

Tags: java, jaxb

Please see code and `CPUUsage` class below.  When I run this code in my `main` method, all of the fields are coming back with zeros instead of "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" as I am expecting.  Do I need to change the field types?  Or maybe add some other sort of annotation?  Or something else?

```
String testXml =
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
    "<env:Envelope xmlns:env=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
        "<env:Body>" +
            "<dp:response xmlns:dp=\"http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management\">" +
                "<dp:timestamp>2015-09-09T04:33:48-04:00</dp:timestamp>" +
                "<dp:status>" +
                    "<CPUUsage xmlns:env=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n" +
                        "<tenSeconds>1</tenSeconds>\n" +
                        "<oneMinute>2</oneMinute>\n" +
                        "<tenMinutes>3</tenMinutes>\n" +
                        "<oneHour>4</oneHour>\n" +
                        "<oneDay>5</oneDay>" +
                    "</CPUUsage>" +
                "</dp:status>" +
            "</dp:response>" +
        "</env:Body>" +
    "</env:Envelope>";

CPUUsage cpuUsage = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(testXml), CPUUsage.class);

System.out.println(cpuUsage);
```

CPUUsage class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CPUUsage")
class CPUUsage {

    private int tenSeconds;
    private int oneMinute;
    private int tenMinutes;
    private int oneHour;
    private int oneDay;

    @XmlElement(name = "tenSeconds")
    public int getTenSeconds() {
        return tenSeconds;
    }

    public void setTenSeconds(int tenSeconds) {
        this.tenSeconds = tenSeconds;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "oneMinute")
    public int getOneMinute() {
        return oneMinute;
    }

    public void setOneMinute(int oneMinute) {
        this.oneMinute = oneMinute;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "tenMinutes")
    public int getTenMinutes() {
        return tenMinutes;
    }

    public void setTenMinutes(int tenMinutes) {
        this.tenMinutes = tenMinutes;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "oneHour")
    public int getOneHour() {
        return oneHour;
    }

    public void setOneHour(int oneHour) {
        this.oneHour = oneHour;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "oneDay")
    public int getOneDay() {
        return oneDay;
    }

    public void setOneDay(int oneDay) {
        this.oneDay = oneDay;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "tenSeconds:" + tenSeconds + "|oneMinute:" + oneMinute + "|tenMinutes:" + tenMinutes + "|oneHour:" + oneHour + "|oneDay:" + oneDay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...if I just strip away all of the envelope info and start at the `<CPUUsage>` element, the code works fine.  So modifying `testXml` to be like below fixes the issue for me:

```
String testXml =
    "<CPUUsage xmlns:env=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n" +
        "<tenSeconds>1</tenSeconds>\n" +
        "<oneMinute>2</oneMinute>\n" +
        "<tenMinutes>3</tenMinutes>\n" +
        "<oneHour>4</oneHour>\n" +
        "<oneDay>5</oneDay>" +
    "</CPUUsage>";
```